# How to justify the text from left in XSL-FO?

Tags: xsl-fo

I have a problem regarding XSL:Fo text. The text should be displayed with left alignment as per the first line. 2nd and subsequent lines of text need to be aligned with the rest of the text of the advert. Presently it looks to be too far to the left and seems to be aligned underneath the bullet point. 
So in summary, the ‘l’ of ‘links’ should be directly underneath the ‘O’ of ‘One’.

The code is-

```
<fo:table width="100%" table-layout="fixed" border-collapse="separate">
                    <fo:table-column column-width="85%" column-number="1"/>
                    <fo:table-body>
                        <fo:table-row height="110mm" >
                            <fo:table-cell padding="2pt" column-number="1">
<fo:block text-align="justify"  font-size="12pt" space-after="3mm">
                                             &#8226;&nbsp;&nbsp;<xsl:value-of select="$advertNotes"/>
                                            </fo:block>
 </fo:table-cell>
</fo:table-row>
</fo:table-body>
</fo:table-column>
</fo:table>
```

The current output is:

> • One bedroom basement flat in the West Station area of Greenock which has excellent transport
>   links with a bus stop and train station nearby. The property consists of a spacious living room, kitchen,
>   bathroom with walk in shower and one double bedroom. There are 8 stairs down to the flat which is
>   then level to the back court area. The property has GCH, double glazing and a controlled door entry
>   system. The property closes on Sunday 8 November 2015 at midnight.

Answer (score 2):

Look at `fo:list-block` and related FOs: http://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#d0e12374

---

Alternatively, you can use the `start-indent` (http://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#start-indent) and `text-indent` (http://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#text-indent) properties, but you'll find it harder to line up the text of the first line and the text of the following lines.